# In C, what is meant by "format argument can be an expression too"?

Tags: c, code-analysis

In the [K&R book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), it shows the following printf statement in the pointers chapter:

```
printf((argc > 1) ? "%s " : "%s", *++argv);
```

I don't understand this line - why are there two %s in here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's equivalent to:

```
if ( argc > 1 )
    printf("%s ", *++argv);
else
    printf("%s", *++argv);
```

That's the ternary conditional operator:

```
(condition) ? (subexpression1) : (subexpression2)
```

The expression evaluates to `subexpression1` if `condition` is `true` and `subexpression2` otherwise.

Comment: Nitpicking: conditional **expression** (the operands are sub-expressions, not statements).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch which part? Also, I favor nitpicking. I want to get my C++ nomenclature as correct as possible.

Comment: You should have written `subexpression1` not `statement1` etc.. so actually `condition ? subexpression1 : subexpression2` because the parenthesis are very often useful, almost always recommended, but not required by the standard; you can write `x?0:1` legally.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch oh. You're right. Will edit. Thanks for that.

Comment: And the question is tagged *C* not *C++*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ah, you're right. Discard that then, I don't care about C nomenclature :P

Comment: But on that matters C and C++ share the same terminology.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to that `printf` is `(argc > 1) ? "%s " : "%s"`, which is a **ternary conditional expression** (see wikipedia's page on [?:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a)) The condition is here `(argc > 1)` the *then* sub-expression is `"%s "` (a litteral constant string), the *else* sub-expression is `"%s"`.

A much more common use of an expression format to `printf` is to call some internationalization or localization function like [gettext](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettext) (actually, many softwares even define a macro named with one character, often `_`, for it).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).  This causes `printf` to use `"%s"` as the format string if `argc` is less than or equal to 1 and `"%s "` if `argc` is greater than 1

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorthand for the if statement, called "ternary operator".

```
(argc > 1) ? "%s " : "%s"
```

means

```
if (argc > 1) 
  "%s "
else
  "%s"
```

The nice thing about it is that while the above is invalid, the ternary operator is a statement and can be used anywhere an expression can be used, so you can, say, assign it to a variable or pass it as an argument to a function call as in your example.

Comment: Nitpicking: not a *statement* but a *conditional* **expression** (having a result, like the `&&` operator has one).

Answer (score 1):

In C, the ? denotes the conditional operator.

The expression:

```
A ? B : C
```

evaluates to B if A is non-zero and evaluates to C if A evaluates to 0.

So in your case, if argc > 1, it will output the current parameters with a space after it. Otherwise, it will output the current parameter with no space

Comment: Better use true and false instead of 1 and 0. If A is 3 (as opposed to 1), it will still evaluate to B.

Comment: Nitpicking: it is not a *statement* but a *conditional* **expression**

Comment: Luchian: there are no true and false values in C, but your case points out that I should have used "non-zero" instead of 1, I fixed this. Basile, I changed it to say expression but technically you can also say that it is a block statement, much like if, while, etc

Comment: No, it is an expression, you can assign it, e.g `x = (y>0)?y:0;`

Answer (score 1):

So that you get a space after the name if there's at least one argument to follow.

And mostly to demonstrate that you could also do:

```
const char *format = "%s";
if (argc > 1)
    format = "%s ";
printf(format, *++argv);
```

Which makes it clearer that the format string can be a variable.  However, you do need to be careful of 'format injection' vulnerabilities.  If the user can control the content of the format string, your program is vulnerable to attack.

Answer (score 1):

Because this expression `(condition) ? (if true) : (if false)` is [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). And `"%s "` will run if condition will be `true`, and `"%s"` if `false`.